# gdb debug variable not in current context

Tags: android, gdb

I am using gdb client server mode to debug android native code. I can set breakpoint at code but after breakpoint hitted, I wish to print the variable value, but it seems doesn't work:

```
(gdb) list
4377        AString mime;
4378    
4379        AString componentName;
4380        uint32_t quirks = 0;
4381        int32_t encoder = false;
4382        if (msg->findString("componentName", &componentName)) {
4383            ssize_t index = matchingCodecs.add();
4384            OMXCodec::CodecNameAndQuirks *entry = &matchingCodecs.editItemAt(index);
4385            entry->mName = String8(componentName.c_str());
4386    
(gdb) print componentName
No symbol "componentName" in current context.
(gdb) info breakpoints 
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0xb65014be frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:4382
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

I set breakpoint at 4382 line, but after it breaked, when I try to print the variable "componentName", it tell me "No symbol "componentName" in current context". it's exactly stop at that line but why it's not in current context?

Comment: Just a quick guess: does a command `objdump -g <your_app> | grep componentName` executed against a binary of your app prints anything?